# C# JSON Deserialization : Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I'm using this C# project which uses [APIs to communicate with the online trading platform Poloniex](https://github.com/Jojatekok/PoloniexApi.Net).

This code is supposed to get balances in a wallet:

```
var x = await polo_client.Wallet.GetBalancesAsync();
```

Although this code gives this error:

> Error getting wallet:Could not create an instance of type Jojatekok.PoloniexAPI.WalletTools.IBalance.
>   Type is an interface or abstract  class and cannot be instantiated.
>   Path '1CR.available', line 1, position 20.

in Helper.cs here:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2202:Do not dispose objects multiple times")]
internal static T DeserializeObject<T>(this JsonSerializer serializer, string value)
{ 
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(value))
    {
        using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
        {
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader, typeof(T));
        }
    } 
}
```

The code to call this is:

```
public T GetData<T>(string command, params object[] parameters)
{
    var relativeUrl = CreateRelativeUrl(command, parameters);
    var jsonString = QueryString(relativeUrl);
    var output = JsonSerializer.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
    return output;
}
```

Can someone tell me why I'm getting an error deserializing this JSON response?

The response is JSON, here is a sample of it:

```
{
"1CR":{"available":"0.00000000","onOrders":"0.00000000","btcValue":"0.00000000"},
"ABY":{"available":"0.00000000","onOrders":"0.00000000","btcValue":"0.00000000"}
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that calls your generic deserialize function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i have done to get it working. Thanks to Chris from Guru.com for getting this working. Great guy and very well priced. You can find him here: http://www.guru.com/freelancers/deatc

```
private IDictionary<string, IBalance> GetBalances()
{
    var postData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var data = PostData<IDictionary<string, Balance>>("returnCompleteBalances", postData);
    var returnData = new Dictionary<string, IBalance>();

    foreach (string key in data.Keys)
    {
        returnData.Add(key, data[key]);
    }

    return returnData;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON or not, the error is self-describing. You can not instantiate an interface or abstract class. They are just blue-prints of what functionality or object structure they'd represent.

For example, you can not do this:

```
var something = new ISomething();
```

but, you can do this:

```
ISomething something = new Something();
```

All you need is just some concrete implementation of that interface. Something like:

```
public JsonReceived : IBalance
{
// rest of the implementation
}
```

Or that might already be provided by the third-party, check their SDK documentation.

Comment: i'm just not used to Generics, haven't programmed in C# in over a year so i'm still getting the hang of them.  If you look at the sample code in the link in the description you could probably figure it out quickly.  ApiWebClient.cs is the calling code and Helper.cs is the deserialization code

Comment: Looking at github, I can see they have concrete implementation of IBalance as Balance. So it would just be a matter of replacing IBalance to Balance in your calling code.

Comment: all i'm using is this to call their code : var x = await polo_client.Wallet.GetBalancesAsync();

Comment: Probably issue with their code then. private IDictionary<string, IBalance> GetBalances() should be private IDictionary<string, Balance> GetBalances()

Answer (score 0):

The error causing due to DeSerialization of an object, that internally creates an Jobject and Cast it as a input Generic, in the above scenario since we cannot create an object of Interface it is throwing an error, 
we can achieve in the below ways according to your solution that is posted in GitHub

add a Hashtable as a generic input to PostData method

change your wallet.cs as 
ex:

```
IBalance CreateFactory(string typeOfBalance, string jsonString)
        {
            IBalance balance = null;
            switch (typeOfBalance)
            {
                case "balanceClassIdentification":
                    balance = new Balance();
                    balance = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Balance>(jsonString);
                    break;
                case "":
                // write logic if Ibalance interface implemented in any childClass ex: class stockBalance: IBalance , then balance = new StockBalance();balance = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<stockBalance>(jsonString);
                default:
                    balance = new Balance();
                    balance = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Balance>(jsonString);
                    break;
            }
            return balance;
        }
        private IDictionary<string, IBalance> GetBalances()
        {
            IDictionary<string, IBalance> data = null;
            var postData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            //var data = PostData<IDictionary<string, object>>("returnCompleteBalances", postData);

            Hashtable output = PostData<Hashtable>("returnCompleteBalances", postData);
            if (output.Count > 0)
            {

                data = new Dictionary<string, IBalance>();
            }
            foreach (string jsonObjKey in output.Keys)
            {
                IBalance balace = CreateFactoty("balanceClassIdentification", output[jsonObjKey].ToString()); // this "balanceClassIdentification" just used as a string but we can add the condition in createFactory according to the type of object that wallet

                data.Add(jsonObjKey, balace);
            }
            return data;
        }
```

Create another intermediate class that implemented Ibalance

like

```
public class BalanceBase: IBalace
 {
 }
```

need to change the balance class

```
 public Balance : BalanceBase
    {
    }
```

if No other classes are implemented for IBalance except balance

you can directly use return type for GetBalance() method 
as IDictionary 
and change the implementaion

```
 private IDictionary<string, Balance> GetBalances()
        {

            var postData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var data = PostData<IDictionary<string, Balance>>("returnCompleteBalances", postData);

            return data;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, although i've been given a much simpler solution that works for me.